# AliExpress retrieve category by id

Tags: aliexpress

I am scrapping AliExpress, all products have data in `window.runParams.data`, but category is provided with id only:

```
   "categoryComponent": {
        "topCategoryId": 44,
        "kidBaby": false,
        "secondLevelCategoryId": 100000306
    }
```

I was not able to find an API to extract category names by ID. Has someone faced the same issue?